# Iterate with map() and delete object with splice without index

Tags: javascript, splice

I can delete an elements with splice but in map cicle index is already known.

```
if ($(this).hasClass("saveFavoriteMedia")) {
                    saveId = $(this).attr("data-id");
                    listFavoriteMedia.map(function (x) {
                        if (x.id == saveId) {
                            //delete x.id; // Work but not delete totaly elements
                            listFavoriteMedia.splice(index, x.id); //index in already know
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 2nd parameter of `map`'s callback funciton - *index*

```
listFavoriteMedia.map(function (x,i) { //i is the index
    if (x.id == saveId) {
       listFavoriteMedia.splice(i, 1);  //observe that 1 is given as second parameter of splice to give count of items to be deleted
    }
});
```

Or if the `id` is unique, use `findIndex`

```
var index = listFavoriteMedia.findIndex( s => s.id == saveId );
listFavoriteMedia.splice(index, 1);
```

If your browser doesn't support arrow function, then

```
var index = listFavoriteMedia.findIndex( function(s){ return s.id == saveId });
listFavoriteMedia.splice(index, 1);
```

Comment: @Andrea Please expand on *Doesn't work*. Which mode?

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter for this purpose;

```
 listFavoriteMedia = listFavoriteMedia.filter(function(x){
      if (x.id !== saveId) {
        return true;
      }
    });
```

Comment: and shorter version with arrow functions `listFavoriteMedia = listFavoriteMedia.filter(x=>x.id! == saveId)`